# c++ constexpr implementation of std::vector

Tags: c++, stl, constexpr

Why doesn't clang support `constexpr std::vector`?

I have a basic implementation which uses `std::allocator` and `std::construct_at`/`std::destroy_at`, and it works well in a `constexpr` function.

https://godbolt.org/z/GfeE4KEPx

```
constexpr auto test() -> int {
    Vec<int> a;
    a.push(1);
    a.push(2);
    a.push(3);
    a.push(4);

    int s = 0;
    for (int i : a) {
        s += i;
    }
    return s;
}

auto main() -> int {
    constexpr int a = test();
    static_assert(a == 10);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that your example works perfectly fine with `std::vector`: https://godbolt.org/z/cKeKeWP57. You can't make `constexpr std::vector` in `main` tho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

c++20 has constexpr `std::vector` and both gcc's libstdc++ (since gcc 12) and clang's libc++ (since clang 15) implement it: https://godbolt.org/z/qsfhxWe6K.

Comment: I try use libstdc++, but constexpr std::vector not working in my case. clang version 16.0.0,
Target: arm64-apple-darwin21.4.0

Comment: You are using "Apple Clang 16", not "clang 16". Apple clang does not support constexpr vector. See [this table](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support#C.2B.2B20_library_features) (search for P1004R2).